# Perl Script for get values range and without duplicate from Symmetric Matrix file

Tags: perl, perl-module

Perl Script for get range value from matrix file

Matrix.txt(content inside)(tap(\t) and newline(\n))

```
\t100050\t100070\t100100\t100200\t100300\n
100050\t1\t0.0890344\t0.361651\t0.266263\t0.368639\n
100070\t0.0890344\t1\t0.0873663\t0.0267854\t0.148069\n
100100\t0.361651\t0.0873663\t1\t0.0423538\t0.269991\n
100200\t0.266263\t0.0267854\t0.0423538\t1\t0.215814\n
100300\t0.368639\t0.148069\t0.269991\t0.215814\t1
```

martix file like
--------100050  100070  100100  100200  100300
100050  1       0.0890344       0.361651        0.266263        0.368639
100070  0.0890344       1       0.0873663       0.0267854       0.148069
100100  0.361651        0.0873663       1       0.0423538       0.269991
100200  0.266263        0.0267854       0.0423538       1       0.215814
100300  0.368639        0.148069        0.269991        0.215814        1

I need only value range(0.3 to 1) with two head label (if less then 0.3 not print)

matrix is symmetric: I.e. $m[$i][$j] == $m[$j][$i] for all indices $i and $j.

$m[$i][$j] == $m[$j][$i] value same

no need print $j $i $v if $i $j $v already exit
I.e  100050 100100  0.361651 so need to print (100100 100050 0.361651)
output.txt

```
Label1  label2  value
100050  100050  1
100050  100100  0.361651
100050  100300  0.368639
100070  100070  1
100100      100100  1
100200      100200  1
100300      100300  1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This isn't a code writing service. What did you try yourself?

Comment: Is the matrix guaranteed to be symmetric? I.e. `$m[$i][$j] == $m[$j][$i]` for all indices *$i* and *$j*? Why is the value `0.266263` being printed when it is less than `0.3`?

Comment: Sorry I have removed 0.266263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($dummy, @headers) = split(/\s+/, <DATA>);
my %seen;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($head, @v) = split; 
    for (my $i = 0; $i < @v; $i++) {
        printf "%10s %10s %8.2f\n", 
            $head, $headers[$i], $v[$i] if $v[$i] >= 0.3 and not $seen{
              join(":", sort ($head, $headers[$i]))
            }++;
    }   
}

__DATA__
--------    100050  100070  100100  100200  100300
100050  1   0.0890344   0.361651    0.266263    0.368639
100070  0.0890344   1   0.0873663   0.0267854   0.148069
100100  0.361651    0.0873663   1   0.0423538   0.269991
100200  0.266263    0.0267854   0.0423538   1   0.215814
100300  0.368639    0.148069    0.269991    0.215814    1
```

Comment: It works thank you very much could remove duplicate?$m[$i][$j] == $m[$j][$i] value same

no need print $j $i $v if $i $j $v already exit I.e 100050 100100 0.361651 so need to print (100100 100050 0.361651)

Answer (score 1):

Lengthy oneliner,

```
 perl -anE 'if(!@h){@h=@F;next} $l{$F[0]}{$h[$_]} = $F[$_] for 1..$#h }{shift@h; $_->[2]<0.3 or say "@$_" for map {$t=$_; map [$t,$_,$l{$t}{$_}], @h}@h' file
```

or more explicit version

```
# opening the file
open my $fh, "<", "file" or die $!;

my @header;  
my %matrix;

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my ($label, @F) = split /\s+/, $line;  # split the line into fields

    if (!@header) {
        @header = @F;
        next;
    }

    # assign the fields through a hash slice
    @{ $matrix{$label} }{@header} = @F;
}
close $fh;

my @arr = map {
  my $label = $_; 
  map [ $label, $_, $matrix{$label}{$_} ], @header;
} @header;

for my $el (@arr) {
    print "@$el\n" if $el->[2] >= 0.3;
}
```

Comment: (1) While I regularily write oneliners over 400 chars long, this isn't exactly good style. Writing the code as a normal script won't make it much longer, but far more readable and easier to understand for OP. (2) Oh why do you almost never add an explanation to the code you are writing? While I tend to write too much, a little enlightenment for those with less Perl-Fu cannot hurt.

Comment: @amon thanks for comment, it always start like short one liner and then it turns into monster.

Comment: I took the liberty of simplifying parts of the code. I especially found the introduction of a `$label` variable beneficial. Using a hash slice is arguably cleaner than looping over indices. The nested map still isn't obvious.

Comment: @amon it seems that `%matrix` doesn't populate properly.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; At the `close`, the `%matrix` holds the correct contents for me, and produces correct output. I made sure that my changes to your code were equivalent.

Comment: It works thank you very much could remove duplicate?$m[$i][$j] == $m[$j][$i] value same

no need print $j $i $v if $i $j $v already exit I.e 100050 100100 0.361651 so need to print (100100 100050 0.361651)